# jqGrid : Need to make a field nonEditable in Edit Window and editable in Add Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a field named userId. I want to make this field editable in Add window and nonEditable in Edit Window. If I set the option editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' }, I found that this field become nonEditable both in Add and Edit Window. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the field as `readonly`, but within your jqGrid function call you can use the `beforeShowForm` callback function which is fired before the window opens.

```
beforeShowForm: function( formId ) {

   $('#userId', formId ).prop( 'disabled', false );        

};
```

This way, the input will only be editable when a user tries to edit the form.

I believe you could also use `$('#userId', formId ).removeAttr( 'readonly' );`

Comment: correct will be usage of `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` and `.attr('readonly', 'readonly');` to set attribute and `.removeAttr('disabled')` and `.removeAttr('readonly')` to remove it. Bootean value an be used only with *properties*: `.prop('disabled', false);` for example.